# Why does the text not fade out?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am starting to learn AngularJS and following a coding example from a textbook. The example code should be having an animation effect for the text to fade out, according to the book, but it doesn't. Does anyone know what should I add or what did I miss? Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
       <title>AngularJS animation installation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <style type="text/css">
        .firstSampleAnimation.ng-hide-add,
        .firstSampleAnimation.ng-hide-remove {
            -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out opacity;
            transition: 1s ease-in-out opacity;
            opacity: 1;
        }
        .firstSampleAnimation.ng-hide {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <div>
        <div ng-controller="animationsCtrl">
            <h1>ngShow animation</h1>
            <button ng-click="fadeAnimation = !fadeAnimation">Toggle fade</button>
            fadeAnimation value: {{fadeAnimation}}
            <div class="firstSampleAnimation" ngshow="fadeAnimation">
                This element appears when the fadeAnimation model is true
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./angular-1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./angular-1.7.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
        app.controller('animationsCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.fadeAnimation = false;
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please use the embedded code snippet tool, to help explain what this code does and does not yet do. And what you what you want it to do.

Comment: Please use the code snippet tool, and attached your js files same as angular js

Answer (score 0):

ngshow should be ng-show

```
 <div class="firstSampleAnimation" ng-show="fadeAnimation">
            This element appears when the fadeAnimation model is true
        </div>
```